# GNU m4 install failed after make command

Tags: cygwin, mingw, gnu, cmusphinx, m4

Here are the steps I took on cygwin:

```
 - wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/m4/m4-1.4.18.tar.gz
 - tar -xzvf m4-1.4.18.tar.gz
 - cd m4-1.4.18
 - ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/
 - make
```

The terminal(cygwin) shows these:

> - C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make  all-recursive    process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, /usr/bin/sed -n
>     s/^(sc_[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*):.*/\1/p ./maint.mk ./cfg.mk, ...) failed.
> - /usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
> - /usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make     all-recursive' make: *** [all] Error 1

Besides, the configure file(please take a look [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m8mhpheo6-omHcdrwUGSFKqRENfrj8Vn/view?usp=sharing)) contains lots of errors.

I want to install **sphinxbase**, but it requires **autoconf** and **automake**, which require **GNU m4**. If you have any method to install autoconf and automake without using the GNU m4, please tell me. Thank you.

*Update:* in the readme, it says that

> By default, the `syscmd' and `esyscmd' macros try to use the first
>   instance of `sh' found by `command -p getconf PATH' at configure time,
>   with a default of `/bin/sh'.  If that default is inappropriate, you
>   can use `./configure --with-syscmd-shell=location' to specify the
>   shell to use.

but I don't know what param to set to.
If I run "command -p getconf PATH" in cygwin, it gives me "/bin:/usr/bin".

Comment: m4 exists as cygwin package...

Comment: You appear to be using a `make` installed along with GnuWin32.  You want to be using the `make` from Cygwin (under `/usr/bin/make`).  Make sure that `/usr/bin` is earlier on your PATH than anything from GnuWin32.  (Incidentally this is not the first time I've seen someone with this problem; I wonder if GnuWin32 does something weird in its installation that is causing it to take precedence on the default `PATH` in Cygwin)